# show data in dropdown list from another model for specific user in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

how are you ?

I have a CRUD for branches , and also I have CRUD for table , and there is a dropdown list to choose the branch in table CRUD , so I want to show the branches that related to user who login in table CRUD unless if he Admin .

this is my code that I tried but not work

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait Tenantable
{
    public static function bootTenantable()
    {
        if (!app()->runningInConsole() && $user = auth()->user()) {
            static::creating(function ($model) use ($user) {
                $model->owner_name_id = $user->id;
            });

            if (!$user->is_admin) {
                static::addGlobalScope('owner_name', function ($query) use ($user) {
                    $query->where('owner_name_id', $user->id);
                });

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it by using these code in my controller

```
public function create()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $branch = null ;

     if ($user->is_admin) {
         $branch = Branch::get(['id', 'code']);
     } else {
         $branch = Branch::where('owner_name_id', $user->id)->get(['id','code']);
     }

    abort_if(Gate::denies('category_create'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

    return response([
        'meta' => [

            'branch'       => $branch,
            
        ],
    ]);
}
```